# Garbage disposer permanently jammed

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink, garbage-disposal

I have a 1/2 horsepower insinkerator (Badger) brand garbage disposer. I noticed poor performance and constant clogging requiring frequent turns with the manual releasing tool underneath. After some time, the tool is now too hard to turn. I removed the disposer and noticed a plastic bag had been ground and stuck below the plates. I removed as much as I could with needlenose pliers.

Even though I can now manually turn the grinding plates with the utility hex tool, the motor power still can't overcome the friction and the grinding doesn't work.

I notice through the top is a hex bolt attaching the top plate to what is probably the drive shaft. I imagine this is siezed. To loosen the grinding plates, do I lock the drive with the hex key at the bottom and unthread the bolt slightly? If so, is this bolt forward spin (righty tighty) or reversed (left threaded)? Is this roughly a good approach?

Comment: I have had some luck with this: try putting ice cubes in and turning the hex key back and forth. This sometimes get small shards of ice to clean the  plates. Then if it will power up dump a couple of glasses of ice down there with the water running to finish cleaning.

Comment: Good chance the plastic got into the bearings, ruining them.  Replacement probably needed of the bearings.  Question is are they replaceable/available.

Comment: Residential Disposals are non serviceable.

Comment: mine was left turn bolt

Comment: There are teardown videos on youtube.   IMO it's more about dissection than repair.  I wouldn't put one back that I've taken apart.

Comment: Have you tried putting WD40 in it and working the blades back and forth? Years ago they were repairable, but normally worth the cost. I do not know about the modern ones.

Comment: Are you sure the plastic bag is the problem? Every disposal I've ever used *had limits* on how much it could process at a time, and you had to learn those limits and adjust your usage to not exceed them. If they are putting plastic bags down the disposal there may be some sort of impairment of judgment. Either stop them from using the disposal, or get a much bigger unit they can't overload.